# Is there (practically) a 1:1 correspondence between an XML schema and an XML namespace?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, xml-namespaces

I get that many XML documents don't use namespaces or schemas. I also understand that you can have an XML document that use a namespace without any associated schema (e.g. Log4J configuration).

While it is technically possible to create an XML schema without an associated namespace, isn't it the case that nearly every XML schema has it's own unique target namespace?

Maybe there are some that constrain multiple namespaces, but I can't think of any examples of that either.

Follow-on question: If you were to version your XML schema (and its URI), would you version your namespace URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is primarily related to the follow-on question.

One pattern that I've seen used (often in large Government e-Filing platforms) is to adopt a major / minor version numbering policy for the schema.  Here, minor version increments indicate a non-breaking schema change, and major version increments are reserved for breaking changes.  The namespace URI then contains the major version number only.

For example, let's say you want to expose a service whose inbound message structure is defined by `submitStuff-v1-0.xsd`.  This could initially have a target namespace URI of (say):

```
http://www.example.org/services/submitStuff/1
```

At some point after v1.0 is released, we introduce a non-breaking change (e.g. adding an optional element).  This would result in the release of `submitStuff-v1-1.xsd`, but the namespace URI would remain as:

```
http://www.example.org/services/submitStuff/1
```

Since the new element introduced in v1.1 is optional, this approach means that users of the service are not forced to update their systems if they do not need to submit the new information (which they would need to do if the namespace URI contained the minor version as well).  Although this may seem like a simple change for the client to make, it introduces additional coupling between the submitting and receiving systems, which may not be desirable.

If, at a later date, a breaking change was introduced (e.g. introduction of a new mandatory element), we would have `submitStuff-v2-0.xsd` with a new namespace:

```
http://www.example.org/services/submitStuff/2
```

Clients of the service would then be able to explicitly assert in the incoming message whether they're attempting to submit a v1.x- or v2.x-compliant request.

During a transition period, the service provider might want to support both v1.x and v2.x messages until all clients have migrated to the new message structure.  By introducing the major version into the namespace it's possible to distinguish between the following scenarios:

- A filer has attempted to submit a v2.x message, but has missed out the mandatory element, in which case an error message should be returned.
- A filer has genuinely submitted a v1.x message, because their system has not yet been upgraded to produce v2.x messages, in which case, no error should be returned.

It would also be possible to use the versioning information embedded in the namespace to do content-based routing - for example, to route all new version messages to a new set of processing servers.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I was trying to ask, but couldn't formulate!  This seems a very common case, and now that I've read it, I've seen it before myself.  I think the convention of upgrading the version of the XML namespace upon making a breaking change in the XML schema is critical for machine client who need to infer the schema from the namespace.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842000/whats-the-best-way-to-indicate-which-version-of-an-xml-schema-should-be-used-to

Answer (score 4):

If the official provider of some XML data did not specify an XML schema, third parties might still write one. In such a case, you may likely end up with more than one XML Schema definition for the same namespace.

You might even want to define a schema for a particular *subset* of a namespace.

For example, when I'd write a CMS that allows only a subset of HTML to be used (for security reasons, e.g. no `<script>` tags), one way is to specify a *new* schema for the HTML namespace, and validate any input against this "safe subset of HTML" schema. After this, while it is still a HTML fragment, it should not contain `<script>` tags, because they were not allowed by the schema.

Answer (score 2):

A schema can describe more than one namespace. It would have to be built from several schema documents (using xs:import), but it would still be one schema.

You can also have several different schemas for the same namespace. You might, for example, want to impose higher quality standards on published documents than on draft documents.

So it isn't really a 1:1 relationship at all.

Comment: It would be a lot more common if it were better supported by the toolsets. I've seen some users go to immense efforts to build tooling to support this scenario, I've seen others just give up and make their schema more strict or more lax than they would really like, rather than having multiple schemas for use at different times.

Comment: Making matters worse, it seems to be a standard practice in REST web services to look at the XML namespace of your application/xml payload in order to asertain the XML schema by which you should interpret the document.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842000/whats-the-best-way-to-indicate-which-version-of-an-xml-schema-should-be-used-to and this http://www.subbu.org/blog/2009/12/media-types-and-plumbing