# Whats the best way to indicate which version of an XML schema should be used to decode an XML web service payload?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, soap, xsd

I am asking this question predominantly in the context of a REST/XML web service API (media type "application/vnd.mystuff+xml"), but perhaps the question is still valid for SOAP based web services.

In the event that the XML schema that describes the vocabulary of our resources/payloads changes, how should I best indicate to the client they should use/expect a newer version of the XML schema?

Should we include a version identifier in the root element like this:

```
<mything xmlns="http://mycompany.com/yadda" version="1.0">
```

or should we just reference the XML schema like this:

```
<mything  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:SchemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/yadda/1 yadda-1.0.xsd"
          xmlns="http://mycompany.com/yadda">
```

or both?

```
<mything  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:SchemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/yadda/1 yadda-1.0.xsd"
          xmlns="http://mycompany.com/yadda"
          version="1.0">
```

Is it common practice to send an XML payload that references an XML schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Use the XML namespace to specify which schema to use.

Comment: So version two of the schema `http://mycompany.com/yadda/2` should use version 2 of the namespace `http://mycompany.com/yadda/2`?  In other words, they need to be versioned at the same time in lockstep?

Comment: Yes, though version 2 of the schema may `<xs:include>` version 1, and use the version 1 types along with the version 2 types.

Comment: I like your answer better than my suggestions...thanks.  However I have to say that doing this implies 1) my client must prior knowledge on how to parse get the version number out of the the namespace URI, and 2) our development team remembers to keep the  namespace version and XML schema version numbers in lock step.  Both of these seem kind of hackish.  I've always kept the namespace the same and changed the schema version number (like Spring).

Comment: Why do they need to know the version number? If you change the schema in the existing namespace, then you are changing the contract in a manner than might not be backwards compatible.

Comment: OK, I think I get it...nobody cares about numbers...the URI is opaque...yes?  So to make it work then, the namespace URI must be the same as the schema URI...yes?

Comment: Yes. The schema `targetNamespace` URI is what _defines_ the namespace the elements belong in.

Comment: Yes, but it is technically possible for one XML namespace to have multiple XML schemas, thus the source of my confusion.  We need to not do have that situation.  We need to force a 1:1 relationship between the XML namespace and an XML schema.